# Error when converting strings to strings.xml, android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I am doing an app for ordering coffee on android studio and it was going all perfect until I changed the strings to strings.xml so they were not hardcoded. Now it starts on my phone and no error appears in android studio before trying it but whenever I press the submitOrder in the phone button it crashes. The error it gives me is:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.android.justjava, PID: 12720
                                                                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508) 
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion: i
                                                                              at java.util.Formatter$FormatToken.unknownFormatConversionException(Formatter.java:1399)
                                                                              at java.util.Formatter$FormatToken.checkFlags(Formatter.java:1336)
                                                                              at java.util.Formatter.transform(Formatter.java:1442)
                                                                              at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1081)
                                                                              at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1042)
                                                                              at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1011)
                                                                              at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1999)
                                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:1527)
                                                                              at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:370)
                                                                              at com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity.createOrderSummary(MainActivity.java:138)
                                                                              at com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity.submitOrder(MainActivity.java:67)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508) 
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Mainactivity.java is:

```
/**
 * <p>
 * package com.example.android.justjava;
 */
package com.example.android.justjava;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

import static android.R.attr.name;
import static android.R.id.message;
import static android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO;

/**
 * This app displays an order form to order coffee.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int quantity = 1;
    int priceOfOneCup = 5;
    int whippedCreamPrice = 1;
    int chocolatePrice = 2;



    ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
     */
    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        //get the name the user has written
        EditText nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_field);
        String name = nameEditText.getText().toString();

        //figure out if the user wants whipped cream
        CheckBox whippedCreamCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_whippedCream);
        boolean hasWhippedCream = whippedCreamCheckBox.isChecked();

        //figure out if the user wants chocolate
        CheckBox chocolateCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_chocolate);
        boolean hasChocolate = chocolateCheckBox.isChecked();

        int price = calculatePrice(hasWhippedCream, hasChocolate);

        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.email_subject, name));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, createOrderSummary(price, hasWhippedCream, hasChocolate, name));
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the plus button is clicked.
     */
    public void increment(View view) {
        //You cannot order more than 100
        if (quantity == 100){
            //Show the client the error
            Toast moreThan100 = Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.toast_too_much), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );
            moreThan100.show();
            return;
        }
        quantity = quantity + 1;
        displayQuantity(quantity);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the minus button is clicked.
     */
    public void decrement(View view) {
        //You cannot order less than 1
        if (quantity == 1){
            //Show the client the error
            Toast lessThan1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.toast_too_less), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );
            lessThan1.show();
            return;
        }
        quantity = quantity - 1;
        displayQuantity(quantity);

    }

    /**
     * Calculates the price of the order.
     *
     * @return total price
     */
    private int calculatePrice(boolean hasWhippedCream, boolean hasChocolate) {

        int basePrice = priceOfOneCup;
        if (hasWhippedCream) {
            basePrice = basePrice + whippedCreamPrice;
        }
        if (hasChocolate) {
            basePrice = basePrice + chocolatePrice;
        }
        int price = basePrice * quantity;

        return price;

    }

    /**
     * Create summary of the order.
     *
     * @param addWhippedCream is whether or not the user wants whipped cream topping
     * @param addChocolate    is whether or not the user wants whipped cream topping
     * @param price           of the order
     * @return text summary
     */
    private String createOrderSummary(int price, boolean addWhippedCream, boolean addChocolate, String name) {
        String orderSummary = getString(R.string.order_summary_name, name);
        orderSummary = orderSummary + "\n" + getString(R.string.order_summary_whipped_cream, addWhippedCream);
        orderSummary = orderSummary + "\n" + getString(R.string.order_summary_chocolate, addChocolate);
        orderSummary = orderSummary + "\n" + getString(R.string.order_summary_quantity, quantity);
        orderSummary = orderSummary + "\n" + getString(R.string.order_summary_price, price);
        orderSummary = orderSummary + "\n" + getString(R.string.thank_you);
        return orderSummary;
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
     */
    private void displayQuantity(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText(number + "");
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            android:id="@+id/name_field"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/toppings"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_whippedCream"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:text="@string/whippedCream"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_chocolate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:text="@string/chocolate"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/quantity"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:onClick="decrement"
                android:text="-" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="@string/initial_quantity_value"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:onClick="increment"
                android:text="+" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:onClick="submitOrder"
            android:text="@string/order" />




    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And finally, strings.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <string name="app_name">Just Java</string>

    <!-- Hint text display in the empty field for the user's name [CHAR LIMIT=20] -->
    <string name="name">Name</string>

    <!-- Heading for the toppings checkboxes [CHAR LIMIT=20] -->
    <string name="toppings">Toppings</string>

    <!-- Name of the CheckBox for whipped cream [CHAR LIMIT=20] -->
    <string name="whippedCream">Whipped Cream</string>

    <!-- Name of the CheckBox for chocolate [CHAR LIMIT=20] -->
    <string name="chocolate">Chocolate</string>

    <!-- Heading for the quantity controller [CHAR LIMIT=20] -->
    <string name="quantity">Quantity</string>

    <!-- Number of cups displayed in the beginning [CHAR LIMIT=5] -->
    <string name="initial_quantity_value">1</string>

    <!-- Heading for the ordering button [CHAR LIMIT=20] -->
    <string name="order">Order</string>

    <!-- Subject line for the order summary email. It will be in the format of
      "Just Java order for Amy" where Amy is the user's name. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="email_subject">Just Java to <xliff:g id="name" example="Miguel Verdaguer">%s</xliff:g></string>

    <!-- Toast message showing an error when more than 100 cups are ordered [CHAR LIMIT=40] -->
    <string name="toast_too_much">You cannot order more than 100 cups</string>

    <!-- Toast message showing an error when less than 1 cup is ordered [CHAR LIMIT=40] -->
    <string name="toast_too_less">You cannot order less than 1 cup</string>

    <!-- Name for the order summary. It will be shown in the format of "Name: Amy" where Amy is the
      user's name. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="order_summary_name">Name: <xliff:g id="name" example="Miguel Verdaguer">%s</xliff:g></string>

    <!-- Whipped cream topping for the order summary. It will be shown in the format of
      "Add whipped cream? true" or "Add whipped cream? false". [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="order_summary_whipped_cream">Add whipped cream? <xliff:g id="addWhippedCream" example="false">%b</xliff:g></string>

    <!-- Chocolate topping for the order summary. It will be shown in the format of
      "Add chocolate? true" or "Add chocolate? false". [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="order_summary_chocolate">Add chocolate? <xliff:g id="addChocolate" example="false">%b</xliff:g></string>

    <!-- Quantity for the order summary.It will be shown in the format of Quantity: 1. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="order_summary_quantity">Quantity: <xliff:g id="quantity" example="1">%i</xliff:g></string>

    <!-- Price for the order summary.It will be shown in the format of Total: 10$. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="order_summary_price">Total: <xliff:g id="price" example="10">%i $</xliff:g></string>

    <!-- Thank you message for the order summary. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="thank_you">Thank You!</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UnknownFormatConversionException` means it has not been able to convert your argument variable, passed to getString(), to the specified format (in your XML file).

You should use `d` to format integer numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `getResources()` like below to get String value from `strings.xml` file

```
getResources().getString(R.string.order_summary_whipped_cream, addWhippedCream);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add getResources(), before the getString method, then it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
MainActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.order_summary_whipped_cream, addWhippedCream);
```

Qualify your resources with getResources for the current activity always.

Comment: Also you had format error exception, therefore invalid data is used,

Comment: also %i and %d are identical , however %i is mainly used for decimals. try  %d.your price is int

Comment: your quantity is also integer,  orderSummary = orderSummary + "\n" + getString(R.string.order_summary_quantity, quantity); use %d instead of %i in your strings.xml file.

Comment: sure no problem. glad to help

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to replace %i with %1$d in your Total string declared in strings.xml
there is format error and it is not really getting the format parameter.
For reference: [Android:StringFormatting](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

Answer (score 0):

what do mean `%i` there? should be `%d` for number.